# How to detect a Command C in my app (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, uipasteboard, uikeycommand

I have a calculator app written in Swift, and it's fully compatible with custom keyboard shortcuts.
I'm trying call a method when the user presses **Command + C**, however, whenever I try to assign the following custom shortcut, it just doesn't work:

```
UIKeyCommand(input: "c", modifierFlags: [.command], action: #selector(commandCAction))
```

The `commandCAction` method is never called, unlike the other shortcuts. I assume this is due to Apple reserving this shortcut. Are there any observers or methods that I can use to detect when the user presses **Command + C** on a physical keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, for some reason this doesn't work on my simulator:

```
UIKeyCommand(input: "c", modifierFlags: [.command], action: #selector(commandCAction))
```

However, when I tried on a physical device, it worked! So that's a solution for someone with the same issue as me.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `UIKeyCommand` says: "Key commands that map to known system events (such as cut, copy and paste) are automatically routed to the appropriate responder methods".

Your best approach may be to subclass the UI elements where you want to intercept the command and implement your own `copy:`.